# Make JS width: toggle has beautiful animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below code:

https://codepen.io/nht910/pen/qBBjgGy

Expand/collapse:

```
$(".post-toc").stop(true).animate({width:'toggle'}, 200);
```

When i click on TOC button, the table of contents will be expanded. But the expand/collapse effect is quiet ugly.

I am just a newbie so can you guys please help me to make expand/collapse has better effect like slide effect,...?

Thank you guys so much.

Comment: What do you mean by _quiet ugly_? Is it because the text is moving around inside the table of contents during the animation?

Comment: @zgood yes, sir. and i don't know how to it has slide effect, like the text, table of contents moving from right to left.

Comment: Try adding this CSS style to your codepen `nav[data-toggle="toc"] { width: 250px; }` and see if that helps the text from moving around.

Comment: @zgood i don't know how but the animation look better a lot. Tks you so much, sir.

Answer (score 1):

Try the JQuery slideToggle() method.

HTML:

```
    <div>
        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
```

JS:

```
        var action = 'click';
        var speed = 1000;
        $('button').on(action, function() {
            $('div').slideToggle(speed);
        });
```